# Adding a value to a list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to add a value to a list of lists.
For input of [[1,2],[2,3]]
I want output of [[2,3],[3,4]]
I can do it with loops:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2],[2,3]]
output = []
for list in list_of_lists:
    sub_output = []
    for value in list:
        sub_output.append(value+1)
    output.append(sub_output)
print(output)
```

Can I do this with list comprehension?

If I do:

```
[value + 1 for list in list_of_lists for value in list]
```

It gives me [2,3,3,4].  Can I get it to keep the sublist format somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you need a nested comprehension:

```
[[item + 1 for item in list] for list in list_of_lists]
```

Another way would be to use `map`:

```
 map(lambda l: map(lambda i: i + 1, l), list_of_lists)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
[ [n + 1 for n in inner_list] for inner_list in list ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest a comprehension into that comprehension. Unpack each sublist to make it easier.

```
[[a+1, b+1] for a,b in list_of_lists]
```